# Why do i have a ClassCastException from convertin an int to an Integer JAVA

Tags: java, exception, jackson, classcastexception, treemap

So i am making a game with Java right now as an exercise and i save a Treemap with Levels in it with Jackson. The Levels arent big and i dont want loading times between Levels, just between whole worlds. So here i come to my problem: The Treemap is defined that way:

```
private TreeMap<Integer, Level> levelList;
```

so everytime i load in a World in the Editor. Thats why i reset the selectedLevel to 0:

```
private void loadWorld() {
    selectedLevel = 0;
    levelList = LevelManager.loadWorld(saveLocations.getLocations().get((selectedWorld)));
    loadLevel();
}
```

(saveLocations is a class that converts the selectedWorld int to a String of the directoy of the World)
and then load in the Level in particular:

```
private void loadLevel() {
    level = levelList.get(Integer.valueOf(selectedLevel));
    levelTiles.clear();
    try {
        levelTiles.addAll(level.getLevelProps());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        resetBuilder();
    }
    try {
        levelTiles.add(
                new GroundTile(level.getSpawn().getX(), level.getSpawn().getY(), 15, 15,EntityState.SPAWNER, 1));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

i get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.get(Unknown Source)
at logicProgramm.Editor.loadLevel(Editor.java:258)
at logicProgramm.Editor.loadWorld(Editor.java:277)
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

This is btw my Levelmanager class:

```
public class LevelManager {

public static void writeJsonWorld(TreeMap<Integer, Level> World, String name) {
    System.out.println("Saver");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        mapper.writeValue(Paths.get("Worlds/" + name).toFile(), World);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Save Failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(name + " with level: " + World.size());
    System.out.println("Save complete");
}

public static TreeMap<Integer, Level> loadWorld(String name) {
    System.out.println("Loader");
    TreeMap<Integer, Level> levelList = new TreeMap<>();
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        levelList = mapper.readValue(Paths.get("Worlds/" + name).toFile(), TreeMap.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        levelList = new TreeMap<>();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return levelList;
}
```

}

Comment: According to the error, your treemap contains strings. Can't say why. Try making a [mre].

Comment: @khelwood That certainly seems to be it, but OP must've consciously tried to force Strings into the map even when they were good and used a Map with type parameters for safety...  Ohh, the TreeMap is from a JSON structure.. check that your JSON doesn't get parsed to a String instead of Integer.

Comment: @xtratic do you know how i can make sure of it, im still a beginner in java and especially with json? I also attached the Levelmanager class

Comment: @Maxim All JSON keys are Strings right? So that makes sense the ObjectMapper is reading your Object as a String-keyed map, and it seems it's getting past the type parameter safety. I'd just switch your map over to use Strings for its keys as well to fit with what the ObjectMapper is giving you; That's probably the simplest solution. If you *must* use Integer keys then you'd need to configure the mapper for that or just take the String-keyed map and convert it.

Comment: @xtratic now i changed the Keys to strings and work with just a simple conversion from int to string for the keys but i am facing another classcastexception with : java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to levels.Level . Do you know why that occurs and how i could change to not face it?

Comment: @Maxim That would be because your JSON data is parsed as a `Map` by `ObjectMapper` again. You would need to look in the `ObjectMapper` API for how to actually map your JSON `Level` data to a `Level` object and vice versa. Here's a short tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial